# Shared domain types and single responsibility principle, how do they work together?

Tags: f#, single-responsibility-principle, onion-architecture

I think my problem is best explained on a hypothetical example.

Suppose you want to design a software for several banks. Two use cases are: calculating a credit score and evaluating taxes. The score does not depend on the taxes and vice versa.

The return type of the credit scoring function is `Score` and the taxes are returned in `TaxAmount`. You want the solution as clean and extensible as possible.

Where would you put the shared/not so shared types?

1. Putting `Score` and `TaxAmount` in one shared type module would violate the single responsibility principle.
2. Putting `Score` and `TaxAmount`in different modules increases the number of files/modules/git submodules very quickly as the code base grows. And the problem spreads through all layers higher up which results in a lot of `open` module statements.
3. Having each function its own type module results in repetition.
4. Not using custom domain types results in losing the benefits of custom domain types.

My constructed onion architecture example:

```ml
namespace Domain.Shared

module Types =

    type Score = 
    | GOOD
    | BAD

    type TaxAmount = int


namespace Domain.Scoring1

module Main =
    open Domain.Shared.Types

    let go input :Score = Score.BAD


namespace Domain.Scoring2

module Main =
    open Domain.Shared.Types

    let go input :Score = Score.GOOD


namespace Domain.ComputeTaxes1

module Main =
    open Domain.Shared.Types

    let go input :TaxAmount = 1


namespace Application

module BankA =

    let standardize x = "a"

    let score input = 
        
        input
        |> standardize
        |> Domain.Scoring1.Main.go

    let computeTaxes input = 
        
        input
        |> standardize
        |> Domain.ComputeTaxes1.Main.go


module BankB =

    let standardize x = "b"

    let score input = 
        
        input
        |> standardize
        |> Domain.Scoring2.Main.go


namespace Infrastructure

module BankA =

    let read filename = "A"

    let score filename = 
        
        filename
        |> read
        |> Application.BankA.score

    let computeTaxes (filename:string) = 
        
        filename
        |> read
        |> Application.BankA.computeTaxes

module BankB =

    let read filename = "B"

    let score (filename:string) = 
        
        filename
        |> read
        |> Application.BankB.score

module Shell =

    [<EntryPoint>]
    let main (args: array<string>) =
        match args with
        | [| "A"; "score"; filename |] -> printfn "%A" (BankA.score filename)
        | [| "A"; "tax"; filename |] -> printfn "%A" (BankA.computeTaxes filename)
        | [| "B"; "score"; filename |] -> printfn "%A" (BankB.score filename)
        | _ -> printfn "Not implemented"
        0
```

Comment: What is the context here? Micro services? Monolith? Desktop? Also why would putting  a series of distinct types in one module break things? Why do you think the single responsibility principle is important?

Comment: Imagine a desktop application. With reference to my example, imagine you change the types for credit scoring. Why should you have to test the tax evaluation? The use cases are independent. But the types are in the same shared module.

Comment: In functional programming you generally don't worry too much about OO concepts like Single Responsibility Principle. Just create types that match your needs, and functions to work on those types, and namespaces and modules to organize things. Of course F# has OO features that you need sometimes, but you usually don't approach writing your program in an OO way, at least not if you can help it.

Comment: actually like SRP and DIP are one of the reasons I embraced functional programming. I even discussed them with 'uncle bob', and failed to get a clear idea of what they actually mean, i now view them as more religious/philosophical in nature than engineering/scientific. Don't worry about it. Write the code in the simplest manner, and refactor it if/when it becomes an issue

Comment: I think the category mistake here is applying SRP to the scope of a whole file. Changes get made and recorded on a per-line basis. The scope of SRP is therefore the lines in your `type` declaration. If you have multiple types in a file because it's convenient for other reasons so be it.

Comment: I think your question is more a FP flavored DDD question than a F# question. See Vaughn Vernon's DDD distilled and Wlaschins DDD made functional. Essentially a shared language between aggregates is encouraged and so is also apparent "code duplication" when a type appears in both aggregate A and B since their semantics most likely are different in the two aggregates.